# file_get_contents not working on localhost but working on online web server

Tags: php, file-get-contents

[image: image of the code]

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://localhost/hts2015/data/functions.php?tag=FIND');


$json = file_get_contents('http://www.hptsprofessional.tk/data/functions.php?tag=FIND');

$jsonD=json_decode($json);
 $no=count($jsonD);
```

Year 2014 I was use same code on my localhost to access data using `file_get_contents()`. It was working fine for me, it works on localhost as well as by changing url it works on online server also. Last Few days I am trying to access same code but it doesn't show any result but when I copied url from the code and paste at browser uri it show me json data output correctly. But I can't access it by using `file_get_contents()`. I am tried to change `php.ini` `allow_url_fopen=On` but fail to get expected result from code. Is anybody help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Please edit your post to put the contents of your code on this website, rather than just providing a link.  (Also you might want to consider adding the PHP tag to this question.)

Comment: Did you restart Apache after changing php.ini?

Comment: yes. I restarted apache but code not work

Comment: get phpinfo and check allow fopen, maybe you change another php.ini

Comment: I changed the correct version of php.ini in apache..but not working for me

Comment: What changed between 2014 and last few days? Same SO? Same Apache intallation?

Comment: Everything is same as previously modified version of code, code works on online webserver. Only it show  problem  to test it on localhost.

Comment: What if you access to http://localhost/hts2015/data/functions.php?tag=FIND via browser?

Comment: Joaquin O It shows me data in  json format but using function file_get_contents it fails

Answer (score 0):

It might be mandatory to specify the user agent header. Try this:

```
$options  = array('http' => array('user_agent' => 'custom user agent string'));
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents('http://domain/path/to/uri', false, $context);
```

To debug this you can try:

```
file_get_contents("http://domain/path/to/uri");
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Can you do the following:

1. check phpinfo() and make sure "Loaded configuration file" is the correct file you changed.
2. set allow_url_fopen=1
3. restart PHP and re-check phpinfo()

Hope it helps!